# How to group the recipe base with the datetime wise

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/leppj.png)We have the below table data format .. we have some recipe  need output current recipe before one recipe data which is all sorting datetime
There is same recipe for B & D but i need recipe (B) set data only ..

```
    declare @tm_variab table (Timecreated datetime,Recipe_Name varchar(80))




    insert into @tm_variab select '2022-10-18 16:50:47' , 'TR1674FSHY'
    insert into @tm_variab select '2022-10-18 16:50:42' , 'TR1674FSHY'
    insert into @tm_variab select '2022-10-18 16:50:37' , 'TR1674FSHY'
    insert into @tm_variab select '2022-10-18 16:50:32' , 'TR1674FSHY'
    insert into @tm_variab select '2022-10-18 16:50:27' , 'TR1674FSHY'  ----- current recipe (A)
    insert into @tm_variab select '2022-10-18 16:50:22' , 'TR1674FSHY'
    insert into @tm_variab select '2022-10-18 16:50:17' , 'TR1674FSHY'
    insert into @tm_variab select '2022-10-18 16:50:12' , 'TR1674FSHY'

    insert into @tm_variab select '2022-10-18 16:50:07' , 'TR1674FSkk'
    insert into @tm_variab select '2022-10-18 16:50:07' , 'TR1674FSkk' ---   recipe (B)
    insert into @tm_variab select '2022-10-18 16:50:07' , 'TR1674FSkk'
    insert into @tm_variab select '2022-10-18 16:50:07' , 'TR1674FSkk'

    insert into @tm_variab select '2022-10-18 16:49:47' , 'TR19556ECDRE'
    insert into @tm_variab select '2022-10-18 16:49:42' , 'TR19556ECDRE'
    insert into @tm_variab select '2022-10-18 16:49:37' , 'TR19556ECDRE'
    insert into @tm_variab select '2022-10-18 16:49:32' , 'TR19556ECDRE' ----   recipe(c)
    insert into @tm_variab select '2022-10-18 16:49:27' , 'TR19556ECDRE'
    insert into @tm_variab select '2022-10-18 16:49:22' , 'TR19556ECDRE'
    insert into @tm_variab select '2022-10-18 16:49:17' , 'TR19556ECDRE'

    insert into @tm_variab select '2022-10-18 16:48:07' , 'TR1674FSkk'  ---   recipe (D)
    insert into @tm_variab select '2022-10-18 16:48:07' , 'TR1674FSkk'





    ;WITH CTE AS
    (
    SELECT 
     Timecreated
     ,Recipe_Name
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Recipe_Name ORDER BY Timecreated DESC) AS rn
     FROM @tm_variab
     )




     , newfinal as (
    SELECT TOP(3)
     Timecreated,
     Recipe_Name
     --, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order BY Timecreated) AS rnii
     FROM CTE WHERE rn=1
     --ORDER BY Timecreated DESC
     )



     select Timecreated, Recipe_Name
     ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(order BY Timecreated) AS rnii
     into #final 
     From newfinal 
     order by Timecreated desc


     select * from #final mm inner join @tm_variab kk on  kk.Recipe_Name=mm.Recipe_Name and kk.Recipe_Name ='TR1674FSkk'  
     drop table #final
```

There is same recipe for B & D but i need recipe (B) set data only ..

Comment: Can you provide the desired ouput based on the data you provided.

Comment: @Dordi  Timecreated Recipe_Name
2022-10-18 16:50:07.000 TR1674FSkk
2022-10-18 16:50:07.000 TR1674FSkk
2022-10-18 16:50:07.000 TR1674FSkk
2022-10-18 16:50:07.000 TR1674FSkk

Comment: Since there isn't a `RecipeBatchNumber` sequence to identify all of the pieces/parts of a recipe that are going into a single batch, what other clues are there? Is the process single threaded so that there can never be rows intermixed (by `Timecreated`) for two (or more) batches? Is there a guaranteed minimum time interval between batches? Is the `Recipe_Name` guaranteed to change between batches or might it repeat? Note that inserting all of the rows for a single recipe with the same value for `Timecreated` would be an improvement, though not ideal.

Comment: @HABO   Is there a guaranteed minimum time interval between batches?  :   Yes min (20 to 30 mints)

Recipe_Name guaranteed to change between batches or might it repeat?  :sometimes only repeat the Recipe name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're looking for gaps in your data based on `Timecreated`.

Here's a query to detect these gaps:

```
SELECT tm.*
    FROM @tm_variab tm
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT *,rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Timecreated DESC) 
        FROM (
            SELECT *,LAG(Recipe_Name) OVER (order by Timecreated ) AS PRECEDENT
            FROM @tm_variab
        )a 
        WHERE Recipe_Name <> PRECEDENT
    )a ON a.Recipe_Name = tm.Recipe_Name AND a.Timecreated = tm.Timecreated AND rn = 2
```

Comment: If you modify the query to output `a.rn` and remove `AND rn = 2` from the `ON` clause I think you'll find that it "works" for the requested recipe, but not so well for the others. [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/_Smqe2iy). Part of the problem is that the `Timecreated` values happen to match for the "recipe (B)" rows, but not for "current recipe" or "recipe (c)". And "recipe (D)" just falls off the end.